# Checkbox in rails active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, activeadmin

I'm a newbie to rails. I'm sorry if I asked something silly. I'm developing a rails application in which I'm using active admin for backend works. In active admin, I want a page to select credit/debit from checkbox. On selecting a particular value, eg. credit, I should be able to open a form which has a text field only for credit. How can I do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK ActiveAdmin does not provide any helpers in order to do that. I would do this by hand using javascript, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906198/dynamically-adjusting-drop-down-fields-on-active-admin-form-rails-3-2), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447164/activeadmin-formtastic-dynamic-select) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370775/create-dynamic-forms-in-activeadmin).

Comment: Thank you. But how can I use Javascript and render partial forms?